# How to convert equation value from string to int in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains some formula and I need its value in result in sql.

Table

```
id Formula
-----------
1  5*power(2.7,n)
-----------
2  5+(5*power(4,n)-1.08
-----------

select REPLACE(Formula, 'n', 2) from table.
```

Here is my problem.
How to get the result after replacing n.

Please guide me

Best wishes

Comment: What result do you want?  `'5*power(2.7, 2)'` seems very reasonable to me for what you are doing.

Comment: I think he want the equasion to be executed as well as the replacement done???

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I feel OP want to execute the formula and gt that result wheras currently he is getting `string` return

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute then dynamic sql may be what you want

```
/*
drop table if exists t;
create table t (id int, formula varchar(100));
truncate table t;
insert into t values
(1 , '5*power(2.7,n)'),
(2 , '5+(5*power(4,n)-1.08)');
*/

select 
concat('select ',
REPLACE(Formula, 'n', 2),
';')
into @sql
from t
where id = 2;

#select @sql;

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

I notice that your second formula is not valid so you may want to build some error checking in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I missed a bracket while entering ---> 5+(5*power(4,n))-1.08. 
How do I get result in column level (Result of all the formula column and w.r.t other columns).

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean

Comment: ID FORMULA VALUE MIN MAX FORMULA VALUE
1 5*power(2.7,n) 300 100 400 ?
2 2  5+(5*power(4,n))-1.08 250 100 500 ?
3 1+(1.9*n))/5 150 10 150 ?
And so on

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This will provide me a row of data. Is it possible to include other columns? Is it possible to get all row and column data and along with result?

Comment: How do the formulae interact with other columns?

Comment: For selection.. ranging between some value.